# DataTables - non-english letters sorting in 1.10

Tags: javascript, datatables, columnsorting

How can I fix the sorting in DataTables 1.10 for non-US letters like `š,č,ť`?

For example, `"š"` is like `"s"` but now these chars (words beginning with these chars) are at the end (after A-Z).

I need it for DataTables version 1.10.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It would really help with a test case, an example of odd values, some info about your locale and language and so on. However, I think you can solve this simply by using `localeCompare()` in a custom sorting plugin, specifying your locale and very important : Setting `sensitivity` level to `'accent'` :

```
jQuery.extend( jQuery.fn.dataTableExt.oSort, {
  "locale-compare-asc": function ( a, b ) {
     return a.localeCompare(b, 'da', { sensitivity: 'accent' })
  },
  "locale-compare-desc": function ( a, b ) {
     return b.localeCompare(a, 'da', { sensitivity: 'accent' })
  }
});
```

usage

```
var table = $('#example').DataTable({
    columnDefs : [
     { targets: 0, type: 'locale-compare' }
  ]
})
```

As said, cannot be sure - the information in OP is sparse, but this should theoretically do the job in most cases. At least it does for me. Remember to pass a valid `locale` string, `da` (danish) is for example purposes only.

demo -> **http://jsfiddle.net/rc4wxnc7/**

Comment: **Thank you very much for your support**, it works great!

Answer (score 0):

My solution is based on https://datatables.net/blog/2017-02-28

Before DataTables init set comparison functions for strings. In my case it was for polish language (pl).

```
let locale = 'pl'
let order = $.fn.dataTable.ext.type.order

delete order['string-pre']
order['string-asc'] = function(a, b) {return a.localeCompare(b, locale)}
order['string-desc'] = function(a, b) {return b.localeCompare(a, locale)}
```

and then init

```
$('.my-table').dataTable( ... )
```